# Utterly confused about concurrent locking

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have two services (one Scheduled Task sending stuff out, one REST service receiving a status message) writing to the same entity, but different fields of the entity.  I have annotaed the reading functions  with `@Lock` and `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` since I want to achieve the following quit simple thing:

1. write extId to entity, send out the entity to external service (with callback URL)
2. release the lock on our entity
3. external service answers to the callback, we read our entity, and write the answer to the status field.
4. release the lock on our entity again.

the answer MUST be written to our entity only after the lock has been released.  Usually (1) should do a ´SELECT...FOR UPDATE`, then` UPDATE`-> (2) If (3) is quicker than superman, it'll wait, beacause (3), too, should to a`SELECT ...FOR UPDATE` thus waiting until the lock (1) has been released, and I'd have it.

It doesn't work, though.  My code just runs through, happily just updating entities, but this never reaches the database, for reasons I can't fathom.  I'm using `@Lock` because `@Transactional` isolation didn't do the trick here - I just didn't find the entity, since (1) hand't commited, yet.
With locking my (3) service finds the entity, can update it in the code, and spring then must throw it away, or something.

Here my sample code - any help very much appreciated, this has cost me quite some time already.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transaction")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
data class PaymentTransaction(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    var id: Long? = null,
    @Column(name = "end_date")
    var endDate: ZonedDateTime? = null,

    @Column(name = "start_date")
    var startDate: ZonedDateTime? = null,
)
```

Rest Service 2:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
class EndResource(
    private val transactionService: MyPaymentTransactionService,
) {
    @Transactional(
        isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ
    )
    @PostMapping("/end")
    fun end(
        principal: Principal,
        transactionStatusEntity: RequestEntity<TransactionStatusResponse>
    ): ResponseEntity<String> {
        val transactionStatus = transactionStatusEntity.body!!
        val transaction = transactionService.findCorresponding(transactionStatus.trans_ref)
        when (transactionStatus.trans_status) {
            "000/01", "000/200" -> transaction?.apply {
                paymentDate = now(UTC)
                paymentErroneous = false
            }
            else -> {
                transaction?.apply {
                    paymentDate = now(UTC)
                    paymentErroneous = true
                }
            }
        }?.apply {
            // paymentErronous is set to true or false above, now set status message
            paymentStatusMessage = (paymentStatusMessage ?: "") + transactionStatus.message
            transactionService.saveAndFlush(this)
        }
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build()
    }
}
```

and here the repository with the @Lock annotation

```
@Repository
interface TransactionRepository : JpaRepository<PaymentTransaction, Long> {
    @Lock(PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Query("select t from Transaction t where t.startDate is null and t.endDate is null ")
    fun findAllOpen(): List<Transaction>

    // called by service "findCorresponding" function
    @Lock(PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    fun findByPaymentExtId(transRef: String): Transaction?

}
```

Comment: Maybe not really an answer but is the explicit locking really needed? You could add a state property to the PaymentTransaction and put it in pending when you are sending the request. Then update the state to completed/error in the callback.

Comment: well, I'm retrieving the whole entity, and want to make sure that only the right parts are written, and nothing is overwritten - that's why I started with locking etc.